# Can we call a stored procedure based on event happening. like triggers

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Can we call a stored procedure based on event happening. like triggers

Comment: You could call a stored procedure (store**D** with a D - **Not** STORE ....) from within a trigger...

Comment: A trigger *is* a special kind of stored procedure that runs when an event occurs. Could you provide details about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want  to know that it is possible or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182602%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and set up an Activation Procedure to be run when an Event occurs.

You can query `sys.event_notification_event_types` to see the type of events available.